# pulling numbers out of text

Tags: python, file, text, calculator

I have a text file that has results listed like this:

> Welcome to your results
>
> The result of 50+25=75
>
> The result of 60+25=85
>
> The result of 70+25=95
>
> The result of 80+25=105

I need python to read the file and pull out the numbers to the left of the "=" and add them up. I have no idea how to get this to work.

```
# take input from the user
print("Select operation.")
print("1.Display The Content of the result file")
print("2.Add two numbers")
print("3.Subtract two numbers")
print("4.Multiply two numbers")
print("5.Divide two numbers")
print("6.Append results to file")
print("7.Display Total of inputs")
print("8.Display Average of inputs")
print("9.Exit")

choice = input("Select an option(1-9):")

if choice == 1:
    file = open('results.txt', 'r')

    print file.read()
    
elif choice >= 2 and choice <= 5:

    l_range = int(input("Enter your Lower range: "))
    h_range = int(input("Enter your Higher range: "))
    num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
    
    if num1 < l_range:
        print "The input values are out side the input ranges \n Please check the numbers and try again" 

    elif num2 > h_range:
        print "The input values are out side the input ranges \n Please check the numbers and try again"

    else:
        if choice == 2:
            print "The result of", num1,"+", num2,"=", add(num1,num2)
            resultstr = "The result of " +  str(num1)  + "+" +  str(num2) + "=" +  str(add(num1,num2))
                        
        elif choice == 3:
            print "The result of", num1,"-",num2,"=", subtract(num1,num2)
            resultstr = "The result of "  +  str(num1) + "-" + str(num2) + "=" + str(subtract(num1,num2))
            
        elif choice == 4:
            print "The result of", num1,"*", num2,"=", multiply(num1,num2)
            resultstr = "The result of "  +  str(num1) + "*" + str(num2) + "=" + str(multiply(num1,num2))

        elif choice == 5:
            print "The result of", num1,"/", num2, "=", divide(num1,num2) 
            resultstr = "The result of "  +  str(num1) + "/" + str(num2) + "=" + str(divide(num1,num2))
            if num2 == 0:

                print "The result of", num1,"/", num2, "=", "You can't divide by zero!"
                                                    
elif choice == 6:
    print("The results have been appended to the file")

    file = open('results.txt', 'a')
                 
    file.write(resultstr + "\n")
                             
    file.close()

           
elif choice == 7:
    print ("Display total inputs")

elif choice == 8:
    print ("Display average of total inputs")

elif choice == 9:
    print ("Goodbye!")

else:
    print("Invalid input")   

lp_input = raw_input("Do you want to perform another action? Y/N:")
    
if lp_input == 'n':
    print("Goodbye!")
```

Comment: Are they all addition and positive numbers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither a code-writing not tutorial service

Comment: this is simple task. what have you tried?

Comment: I realize this probably a simple task  but not sur ehoe to split the strrings then use them.

Comment: @jonrsharpe we can close it if you want. i am on multiple vba forums and assist new vba users on a reg basis. I have written 90% of my application but don't know where to start for this portion. I have read multiple tutorials on reading/splitting text from file but can't figure out how to combine the process.

Comment: Split by `=` and select the first part. Split by space and select the last part. Split by `+` and you are done.

Comment: @dlask this is part of a calculator app so the results could be "+" "-" "/" "*"

Comment: This information is missing in your question. Anyway, my suggestion is still valid.

Comment: So provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code and a concise description of the issue.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited post to show the code I havewritten so far utilizing tutorials. I dont know where to begin to make my option 7 work. I apologize for not having more to start with

Comment: A **minimal example**. Read the advice on [ask]

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from the question, a simple regex match would solve the problem. You may do it like so:

Read the file line by line.
Make a regex pattern like so, to get the data from the string:

`>>> pattern = "The result of (\d+?)[+-/*](\d+?)=(\d+).*"`

Say if a line from the file is stored in the variable result:

`>>> result = "The result of 25+50=75"`

import the `re` library and use the match function like so which gives you the data from the string:

`>>> s = re.match(pattern, result)`

`>>> print s.groups()`

`('25', '50', '75')`

You can then get the numbers from this tuple and do any operation with it. Change the regex to suit your needs, but given the contents of the file at the start, this should be fine.

Comment: @kunalaggrarwal how do I get it to just get the lines that match the pattern?

Comment: `file = open('results.txt', 'r')
        
        File.each_line('results.txt') do |li|
        
        puts li if (li["The result of (\d+?)[+-/*](\d+?)=(\d+).*"])
        
        end`

Comment: @ScottMorin `s = re.match(pattern, result)` will give you `None` in `s` if the line does not match. You can check that in an if statement like `if s:`, this will be true only if the line matches.